# Is visiting China for the funeral of a parent a guaranteed reason to earn an expedited visa?

Tags: visa, china

Is visiting China for the funeral of a parent a guaranteed reason to earn an expedited visa?

I would assume filial piety makes the consulate unethical to deny a person an expedited visa to go to the funeral of a parent/family member.

Asking for a friend.

Comment: I doubt that anything is *guaranteed*, especially right now with the Covid-19 situation in China. Many countries have entry policies (both permanent and temporary) that are unethical in the strictest sense, but that doesn't stop them from still being enforced.

Comment: Governments around the world denied their *own citizens* the opportunity to go to a relative’s funeral during Covid. China is implementing strict lockdowns in many areas, news reports say funerals are suspended in some cities eg Beijing. It seems pretty unlikely a visa would be granted at all, IMHO